# AWS: Use EC2 instance creation to trigger lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am compiling a fairly complex CloudFormation template and at some point I am creating an `ec2` instance;

I want to create a `lambda` function that:

- takes as input parameter the public IP of the instance created in this CF stack
- opens a security group port for that particular IP (the security group is **not** part of the specific CF template and it belongs to a **different region**).

Is this possible?

Ι am asking because (among others) `ec2` is not listed as a potential lambda trigger in the console and wanted to see whether there is a simpler way around this than posting details about the creation in an `sns` or `sqs` which then in turn triggers the lambda.

Comment: You can use CloudWatch events to achieve this. Refer this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two options that I can think of:

1. As user @krishna_mee2004 stated, you can use CloudWatch to listen on your EC2 instance and this in turn will trigger your lambda.
2. On your EC2 instance, there is a field called `User data` under the Instance Details. In `User data` you can add commands that should be ran whenever your EC2 instance is deployed. From here you can invoke your lambda.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) is documentation on EC2 user data. 
[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-userapp.html) is documentation on invoking your lambda from the CLI.

Personally, I'd recommend option 1 because I prefer using AWS tools whenever I get the chance and CloudWatch is a perfect example of this. However, option 2 might give you more control over what payload is sent to the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the recommended way to use a Security Group.

If you wish to allow the EC2 instance to have inbound access to the security group, you should do the following:

- Create a security group for the EC2 instance being launched. Let's call it `Instance-SG`
- Create a security group for the resource that you want EC2 to be able to access (such as a Load Balancer, database or other EC2 instance). Let's call it `Resource-SG`
- Add an entry to `Resource-SG` that permits inbound access from `Instance-SG`

That's it! Now, any EC2 instance that is associated with `Instance-SG` will be granted inbound access into `Resource-SG`. There is no need to put specific IP addresses in the Security Group.

Comment: Yes but the instance and the resource are in different regions

Comment: that was my fault not mentioning it in the first place, I updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The easiest might be to have the EC2 instance add itself to the security group.

Simply put this in the User Data for the EC2 instance and make sure it is assigned an IAM Role with sufficient permissions:

```
IP=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/`

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "Resource-SG" --protocol tcp --port 80  --cidr $IP/32 --region OTHER-REGION
```

Comment: That is indeed the simplest solution! My main concern is that I want the particular rule __removed__ as soon as I tear down my stack; that's why I thought of `lambda` as being able to respond (via Cloudwatch apparently) to stack (or resource) creation / deletion

Comment: Yes, that is starting to look like a good use-case for CloudWatch Rules to trigger a Lambda function. I suggest you put a **Tag** on such an instance with the security group you want updated (eg Name=RegsterMe,Value=sg-1234). The Lambda function can then look for the tag. If present, it adds/removes the instance from that security group. That way, you don't need to code "magic values" into the Lambda code itself and the function can be used for different scenarios.